# RazorEngine Dynamically Add in cshtml

Tags: c#, plugins, nopcommerce, razorengine, onactionexecuted

I have a problem about using of RazorEngine While Creating plugin in nopcommerce.
My source code in the OnActionExecuted is:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
   var m = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
   string newTag = @"@using Nop.Plugin.Misc.Helper.Extensions; @using Nop.Web.Framework.ViewEngines.Razor;
   <div class='inputs date-of-birth'/ <label>@T('Account.Fields.DateOfBirth'):</label></div>";
    var res = "Hello World";
    if (m != null)
   {
     var model = m.Model as RegisterModel;
     var service = Engine.Razor;   
     service.AddTemplate("templateRegister", newTag);
     service.Compile("templateRegister");
     res = service.Run("templateRegister", null, model);
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(res);
   }
}
```

But while compile and run, i was encounter with this error:

> RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException: 'Errors while
>   compiling a Template. Please try the following to solve the situation:
>   * If the problem is about missing/invalid references or multiple defines either try to load 
>       the missing references manually (in the compiling appdomain!) or
>       Specify your references manually by providing your own IReferenceResolver implementation.
>       See https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html for details.
>       Currently all references have to be available as files!   * If you get 'class' does not contain a definition for 'member': 
>           try another modelType (for example 'null' to make the model dynamic).
>           NOTE: You CANNOT use typeof(dynamic) to make the model dynamic!
>       Or try to use static instead of anonymous/dynamic types. More details about the error:
>    - error: (36, 79) Too many characters in character literal Temporary files of the compilation can be found in (please delete the folder):
>   C:\Users\Chegini.h\AppData\Local\Temp\RazorEngine_tfr2i1nu.3fl The
>   template we tried to compile is: 
>   ------------- START ----------- @using Nop.Plugin.Misc.NchShamsiDate.Extensions; @using
>   Nop.Web.Framework.ViewEngines.Razor;
>
> @T('Account.Fields.DateOfBirth'):

Please advice me,if possible!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `@T('Account.Fields.DateOfBirth')`, it needs double quotes **`@T("Account.Fields.DateOfBirth")`**